# Copy data into next empty cell in specific rows based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet ("Rough Data"), with 4 fixed columns and rows of varying data.
A is my client ref numbers.
B and C are unimportant data.
D is the column with my results.

Column A will have client references that may be the same (e.g. 100 rows, and 70 different references, therefore 30 are duplicates).
I know how to first copy Column A into another sheet ("Finished Data").

I then want to run some sort of macro to insert the data from column D ("Rough Data") into the next available column cell for the particular reference in "Finished Data".
e.g., if #12543 has 3 rows on Rough Data (row 2, 3 and 4), I want to search for that client ref #12543 on Finished Data, and insert the data from D2, D3 and D4 into neighbouring cells (so, if #12543 is A2 on Finished Data, the new data would be copied into B2, C2 and D2.

I get the macro to copy, but when it registers that there is already data in the D column on the Finished Data sheet, it skips to the next unique reference. I can't get it to enter data in the next available cell for that unique reference.

```vb
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Finished Data").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, 
    Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("Rough Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
    i = 2
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value > 0
        ref = Cells(i, 1).Value
        n = 2
        done = False
        
        Do While done = False
            check = Sheets("Finished Data").Cells(n, 1).Value
            If check > 0 Then
                If check = ref Then
                    Sheets("Finished Data").Cells(n, 5).Value = Sheets("Rough Data").Cells(i, 4).Value
                    done = True
                End If
            Else
                Sheets("Finished Data").Cells(n, 1).Value = Sheets("Rough Data").Cells(i, 1).Value
                Sheets("Finished Data").Cells(n, 2).Value = Sheets("Rough Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
                Sheets("Finished Data").Cells(n, 3).Value = Sheets("Rough Data").Cells(i, 3).Value
                Sheets("Finished Data").Cells(n, 4).Value = Sheets("Rough Data").Cells(i, 4).Value
                done = True
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Loop
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that SO is not a code writing service. If you have made an attempt to your problem and have a code that's not working, please edit your question, include the code then explain how is your code not working.

Comment: What *specifically* is the problem you're having with this? Which part of it is giving you problems?  Looping over the source rows?  Finding a match on the second sheet?   What code do you have so far?

Comment: specifically, if i have row 2 and row 3 with the same reference in column A, but different data in column D, when i copy the data from the Rough sheet to the Finished sheet, it will only copy of the data in cell D3.  the data in cell D2 is ignored, as the reference is  already on the Finished sheet with data in column D for that row.  I can't seem to get it to put the data in the next available cell in the same row (e.g. column E).  I have clients that appear 3 or 4 times per week, with differing results, and i want to collate all those results on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Match() like this:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim wsRough As Worksheet, wsFinished As Worksheet, c As Range, m
    
    Set wsRough = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rough Data")
    Set wsFinished = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rough Data")
    
    wsFinished.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents 'remove any data data (leave headers)
    
    Set c = wsRough.Range("A2") 'first client ref#
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wsFinished.Columns(1), 0)    'look for a match
        If IsError(m) Then                                          'if m is error then no match found
            m = wsFinished.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find next empty row
            c.Resize(1, 3).Copy wsFinished.Cells(m, "A")            'copy first 3 cells
        End If
        'copy col D value
        wsFinished.Cells(m, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
    
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next source ref
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim
thanks for the above.  Not sure what i am doing wrong, as that just seems to delete all my data :-(

Comment: Hi Tim
I stand corrected!  it works (having a blond moment)!  thank you for the assistance, your code is definitely better than what i was trying to cobble together